# Python Datacompy: How to get the full comparasion report

Tags: python

I'm comparing two huge files with Datacompy, the comparaison report shows the differences for only 10 rows. Is there a method to get the full comparaison ?

Answer (score 1):

The sample and column counts in the report defaults to `sample_count=20` and `column_count=10`, so one potential solution will be to increase these numbers.

```
compare = datacompy.Compare(
    df1,
    df2,
    join_columns='acct_id',  #You can also specify a list of columns
    abs_tol=0, #Optional, defaults to 0
    rel_tol=0, #Optional, defaults to 0
    df1_name='Original', #Optional, defaults to 'df1'
    df2_name='New' #Optional, defaults to 'df2'
    )
compare.matches(ignore_extra_columns=False)
# False

# This method prints out a human-readable report summarizing and sampling differences
print(compare.report(sample_count=50, column_count=15 #specify sample_count and column count here))
```

Answer (score 0):

> The dataframes that you’re comparing have to fit in memory. In
> comparison with SAS PROC COMPARE which can operate on datasets that
> are on disk, this could be a constraint if you’re using very large
> dataframes.

https://capitalone.github.io/datacompy/pandas_usage.html#limitations

Maybe its because you dont write report into a file

```
with open('//Path', encoding='utf-8') as report_file:
    report_file.write(compare.report())
```

you can use something like that.

And check datacompy limitations.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to export csv's with all the records. DataComPy offers the possibility to export records in dataframe 1, in dataframe 2, in the intersection, and the mismatching records in the intersection.

For that, you can:

##### Save results into variables and export to csv

```
only_df1 = compare_app.df1_unq_rows
only_df2 = compare_app.df2_unq_rows
intersection_df1_df2 = compare_app.intersect_rows
intersection_df1_df2_unequal = compare_app.all_mismatch()

only_df1.to_csv('01_only_in_df1.csv')
only_df2.to_csv('02_only_in_df2.csv')
intersection_df1_df2.to_csv('03_intersection_df1_df2.csv')
intersection_df1_df2_unequal.to_csv('04_intersection_df1_df2_unequal.csv')
```

I hope it helps.

Regards,